# Javascript : How to define an array of booleans with 60 elements in it

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript : How do I define an array of booleans of a certain length without having to define manually, e.g. an array with 60 elements in it ?

Comment: Use bitmasking, and save some memory..

Comment: Array(60).fill(true)

Comment: Array(60).fill(true) ist not as fast as 
`let _size = 60
while (_size--) {
  _array.push(true)
}`

Comment: @pungggi benchmarking or link to support?

Answer (score 87):

```
var anArrayOfBooleansWith60ElementsInIt = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, 
true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, 
true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, 
true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, 
true, true, true, true, true, true, false];
```

Comment: I hope you didn't type that out by hand :).

Comment: Wow! I never saw an *array of Booleans with 60 elements in it*

Comment: My apologies to all of you guys for that stupid question. Will never happen again. I do however have an interesting question to ask, but cannot do so since I cannot ask anymore questions. Will appreciate if you can have the ban lifted please. My apologies again for that dumb question. I should have read more before asking.

Comment: Can anyone help lift the ban me so I can post more questions please. This wont happen again and I am sorry for posting such a dumb question.

Comment: Hahahahaha.  Oh my god, I just seriously lol'd so hard.

Comment: @sbguy I don't think was a stupid question. I had the same question and came to here only to find it wasn't possible the way I intended it.

Comment: Are you serious ? O.o

Comment: Congrats, you are now twitter famous ;)
https://twitter.com/Ashot_/status/1329427975423594498

Answer (score 47):

JavaScript is loosely typed, so you can't really do that.  You can of course create a 60 element array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

```
var a = new Array(60);
```

And then you could just fill it with *false* or something.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) { a[i] = false; }
```

Comment: var a = new Array(60).fill(false);

Comment: This is an excellent approach! I appreciate the humor above, but is there any reason why this solution by Corbin and @james-little should be avoided?

Comment: yeah probably you want to avoid new keyword here, unless you want it's side effects.